# KineticJS leaving behind ghost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kineticjs

So i recently added Kinetic.JS **v4.6.0** to my app, and tested out a simple rectangle drag and drop.

Works fine on the web browser, but as soon as i use it on a mobile, it bugs out and leaves a ghost of the rectangle after dragging.

I'm basically using the same script as the [demo](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-mobile-events/), without the touchStart/touchEnd events, i'm also using JQuery 1.9.1 and JQueryMobile-1.3.2.

How can i get rid of this effect, i've tried clearing the layer on touchStart and drawing the stage again on touch End but the ghost stays there.

**Edit**
My device is a Galaxy S2 running 4.2.2 and the ghosting happens, but the app works fine on the Ipad.

**/index.JS**

```
$( window ).on( "pageinit", function ( event ) {
stage = new Kinetic.Stage( {
    container: "container",
    width: 500,
    height: 500
} );

MapLayer = new Kinetic.Layer()

var Rect = new Kinetic.Rect( {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable: true
} );

MapLayer.add( Rect );
stage.add( MapLayer );
```

**Index.HTML**

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kinetic-v4.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<title>Mobile OneStop</title>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

( I might do a badly drawn paint image to show this off if people do not understand)

**Edit**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2odJ.jpg - 
Ive changed a lot of the code since posting this, but the issue still remains.

Comment: Did you try on multiple devices? Also, do you receive the ghosting on one his demos? Canvas animation uses a lot of CPU and choppiness may vary.

Comment: Tested on my Galaxy S2 and it doesnt work, tested on an Ipad and it works, trying to test on other android devices now. Does android have problems with HTML5 Canvas or something?

Comment: You could take a screen capture on your GS2 and post it here. That would help.

Comment: added a screenshot, the background layer still moves,  i read that this issues is common on android 4.1 and up and only applies to the first object in the canvas, anything added after that it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to stop the ghosting from happening, I have just put a huge white rectangle behind the  objects i need to be drawn, not elegant but it gets the job done.